# Environment with no below displayed skip but working \intertext

Tags: spacing, amsmath, intertext

I would like to have an environment where there is no below display skip inserted following a display mode equation.  The definition

```
\newenvironment{NoBelowDisplaySkip}{%
    \begingroup
    \belowdisplayskip=0pt\relax%
    \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt\relax%
}{%
    \endgroup
}
```

works fine. However, when I attempt to make use of `\intertext{}`, there is missing vertical space before the start of the `\intertext{}` (see text in red):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}% so I can highlight where the problem is

\pagecolor{white}

\newenvironment{NoBelowDisplaySkip}{%
    \begingroup
    \belowdisplayskip=0pt\relax%
    \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt\relax%
}{%
    \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\MyText}[1]{%
    \begin{align*}
        F &= ma \\
        \intertext{\color{#1}and another not totally unrelated equation}
        E &= mc^2.
    \end{align*}
    Some follow on text%
}

\begin{document}
Normal \verb|{align*}| with \verb|\intertext{}|
\MyText{black}.
% ----------
Repeat, but wrapped in the \verb|{NoBelowDisplaySkip}| environment:
\begin{NoBelowDisplaySkip}%
\MyText{red}
\end{NoBelowDisplaySkip}.%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\intertext` is separated from the formulas above and below not only using `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` (and their short versions), but also using `\l_MT_above_intertext_sep` and `\l_MT_below_intertext_sep`. They can be adjusted, though the result isn't perfectly the same as they are dimens, not skips, so they can't shrink or stretch. The following example assigns `\l_MT_above_intertext_sep` the value of `\belowdisplayskip` (and short version as well). Another change is that you don't really need `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` because an environment forms a group automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}% so I can highlight where the problem is

\pagecolor{white}

\catcode`\_=11
\newenvironment{NoBelowDisplaySkip}{%
    \l_MT_above_intertext_sep=\belowdisplayskip
    \l_MT_above_shortintertext_sep=\belowdisplayshortskip
    \belowdisplayskip=0pt
    \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
}{%
}
\catcode`\_=8

\newcommand*{\MyText}[1]{%
    \begin{align*}
        F &= ma \\
        \intertext{\color{#1}and another not totally unrelated equation}
        E &= mc^2.
    \end{align*}
    Some follow on text%
}

\begin{document}
Normal \verb|{align*}| with \verb|\intertext{}|
\MyText{black}.
% ----------
Repeat, but wrapped in the \verb|{NoBelowDisplaySkip}| environment:
\begin{NoBelowDisplaySkip}%
\MyText{red}
\end{NoBelowDisplaySkip}.
Again normal \verb|{align*}| with \verb|\intertext{}|
\MyText{black}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason to use `\catcode` changes instead of the usual `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff`?

Comment: No reason. I just don't have any experience with LaTeX3.